# It is possible create records in controller specs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise, factory-bot

I've wrote the follow example:

```
it "should assign @services containing all the current user services" do
  customer = FactoryGirl.create(:user, fullname: "Iris Steensma")
  sign_in customer
  service = FactoryGirl.create(:service, user: customer)
  puts "Service.count = #{Service.count}" # Service.count = 0
  get :home
  assigns[:services].should eq([service])
end
```

The action controller as:

```
def home
 #@services = curent_user.posted_services
 @services = Service.all
end
```

And factories.rb contains:

```
FactoryGirl.define do

  sequence :address do |n|
    "Street #{n}"
  end

  factory :user do
    fullname "Foo Bar"
    email { "#{fullname.gsub(' ', '.').downcase}@example.com" if fullname }
    password "secret"
  end

  factory :preference do
    profile "customer"
    user
  end

  factory :service do
    status :pending
    source_addr { generate(:address) }
    target_addr { generate(:address) }
    passenger "Mis Daysi"
    start_at Time.now
    offer 5
    payment "cash"
    user
  end

end
```

Why Factory Girl can't create the Service record? The factory works fine in the test environment "rails c test"

Here is the rspec ouput:

```
Failures:

  1) UsersController GET home should assign @services containing all the current user services
     Failure/Error: assigns[:services].should eq([service])

       expected: [#<Service:0x460d8ea @name="Service_1003">]
            got: []

       (compared using ==)

       Diff:
       @@ -1,2 +1,2 @@
       -[#<Service:0x460d8ea @name="Service_1003">]
       +[]

     # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:26:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 1.03 seconds
3 examples, 1 failure
```

Comment: One problem with your controller action is it should be `@services = Service.all` rather than `@services = Service.All`

Comment: Also, could you post the error you're getting?

Comment: The two arrays are different objects, but their content could be the same

Comment: @JoshuaRieken, in effect, the controller definition is like you say (Service.all).

Comment: To make sure there's not a validation preventing the service from being created, you could `service = customer.services.create!(attributes_for(:service, user: customer))`

Comment: @JesseWolgamott, I've used the create! method and the result is the same (There is not  other different error message). I think that the problem is with the model associations and factory girl. When I assign User.all to the services instace variable, assigns[:services] is not empty in the example body, obviously the test fails.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the correct syntax is:

```
assigns(:service).should eq([service])
```

According to the rspec documentation `assigns[key]` used to be the way to assign instance variables which looks a little like what's happening for you.

https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails

Comment: Ah, sorry. I misunderstood.

Answer (score 0):

First, the user: customer here is not needed, since you are using customer.services.create that already does that

```
service = customer.services.create(attributes_for(:service, user: customer))
```

Second, try this, after service = customer.services.create do something like

```
service.valid?
puts service.errors.inspect
puts service.user == customer
```

maybe you can also try

```
service = FactoryGirl.create(:service, :user => customer)
```

also, are you sure the association is defined on Service class?

doesn't

```
#<Service:0x57856f4 @name="Service_1003">
```

should be

```
#<Service:0x57856f4 @name="Service_1003" user="<your customer object">
```

?

how is your factory for service defined?

Comment: Thanks @arieljuod, I got more information to inspect what is happening. I modified the example as you suggest, so: `service.valid?` returns true, `service.user == customer` returns false (uhmmm??). `puts service.errors.inspect` returns `#<ActiveModel::Errors:0xa768e8c @base=#<Service:0x54a1348 @name="Service_1003">, @messages={}>` and `service.user` returns `Service_#<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_1:0xa513934>`, the last one is so strange. Also, change `service = customer.services.create` by `service = FactoryGirl.create` and the result is the same.

Comment: The association is ok, I get the expected results in rails console using the test environment (rails console test)

Comment: maybe there's something wrong with the factory, can you post that code?

Comment: I pasted the factories.rb file